# C rounding of unsigned->float conversion where src is equal distant from its rounded up or down value?

Tags: c, floating-point, rounding

Looking at round trip conversion in C from unsigned to float to unsigned, I was a bit suprised to see that unsigned to float rounding of a value like:

```
0x80000080
```

is rounded down to (float)0x80000000 instead of up to (float)0x80000100.  Note that since we have 1+23 effective mantissa bits available in a float we can exactly represent any unsigned values that have the lowest 0xFF bits clear.  Yes, both of these rounding possibilities are 128 distant from 0x80000080, so it could be argued that this is choice is arbitrary.

However, consider the rounding of the full range of values in the 256 bit region starting at 0x80000000

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   unsigned i ;

   for ( i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i++ )
   {
      unsigned v = 0x80000000 + i ;

      int roundUpDiff = 256 - i ;

      float f = (float)v ;
      unsigned r = (unsigned)f ;

      printf( "0x%08X = 0x80000000 + %d = 0x80000100 - %d -> 0x%08X\n", v, i, roundUpDiff, r ) ;
   }

   return 0 ;
}
```

A subset of the output from this is:

```
0x8000007C = 0x80000000 + 124 = 0x80000100 - 132 -> 0x80000000
0x8000007D = 0x80000000 + 125 = 0x80000100 - 131 -> 0x80000000
0x8000007E = 0x80000000 + 126 = 0x80000100 - 130 -> 0x80000000
0x8000007F = 0x80000000 + 127 = 0x80000100 - 129 -> 0x80000000
0x80000080 = 0x80000000 + 128 = 0x80000100 - 128 -> 0x80000000
0x80000081 = 0x80000000 + 129 = 0x80000100 - 127 -> 0x80000100
0x80000082 = 0x80000000 + 130 = 0x80000100 - 126 -> 0x80000100
0x80000083 = 0x80000000 + 131 = 0x80000100 - 125 -> 0x80000100
```

If the direction of the rounding choice for all values is counted, we see that there is rounding down of all the values in the 0x80000000-0x80000080 range (i.e. 129 of the 256 values rounded down), and rounding up of all the values in the range 0x80000081-0x800000FF (i.e. 127 of the 256 values rounded up).

Using a decimal rounding analogy, if we were rounding to the nearest ten, this seems like a decision to round values:

```
9,8,7,6
```

up towards ten, but to round the digits:

```
5,4,3,2,1,0
```

down towards zero?

What's the motivation for a rounding mode like this (I presume it's the default rounding mode since I've not explicitly specified otherwise)?

Comment: This is probably round-to-even, which has some nice properties.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical FP rounding mode (which can be controlled) is round to nearest, ties to even.
Integer rounding is towards 0 for compliant C compilers.  Also see @Pascal Cuoq comment.

[Edit] First post was `signed`.  Changed to `unsigned` per OP.

Example: `uint32_t` to `float` to `uint32_t`

```
8000007F 0x1.000000p+31 80000000  Nearer to lower value, round down   
80000080 0x1.000000p+31 80000000  Tie, round down as its "even"  
80000081 0x1.000002p+31 80000100  Nearer to higher value, round up   

8000017F 0x1.000002p+31 80000100  Nearer to lower value, round down  
80000180 0x1.000004p+31 80000200  Tie, round up as its "even"  
80000181 0x1.000004p+31 80000200  Nearer to higher value, round up
```

"Even" in this context means of the 2 choices to rounded to, choose the one with the least significant bit of the `float` set to 0.

---

Ref

The C11dr Annex F.3 (normative) IEC 60559 floating-point arithmetic says

— The conversions from integer to floating types provide the IEC 60559 conversions from integer to floating point.
— The conversions from floating to integer types provide IEC 60559-like conversions but always round toward zero.

Comment: Floating-point to integer rounds towards zero (“truncates”) because the standard says so (not “almost always”). Integer to floating-point rounding is implementation-defined, and most implementations define it as “according to the FPU's rounding mode”.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Doesn't Annex F (if supported) require it to be according to the rounding mode?

Comment: @R..  C11dr F.3 1 does say "The conversions from floating to integer types provide IEC 60559-like conversions but always round toward zero."

Comment: @R.. Nothing in Annex F on the conversion from integer to floating-point. I would say that no additional constraint is added to those of 6.3.1.4:2 (C99). One rationale may be that even processors that handle IEEE 754 basic operations in hardware may leave conversions to/from integers to software (e.g. PowerPC).

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq My "Integer rounding is almost always round toward 0" stems from pre C99 that allowed integer division to do something other than "truncation toward zero".  But saying "Floating-point to integer rounds towards zero" is certainly more up-to-date and applicable here.  Thus my edit to your comment.